# Como seleccionar hijo en Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sass, pug

```
section.text-overlap-img
.container
    .row.justify-content-around.adjust-height
        .col-md-5
            .wrapper-img.bg-line-white
                img(src="img/johan-cruyff.png")
        .col-md-5
            .wrapper-text
                h2.title-golden 
                    |LA
                    br
                    | REVOLUCIÓN
                    br
                    | CRUYFF
                p
```

y quiero seleccionar el col-md-5 en jquery, refiriendome al hijo de .adjust-height, como podría hacerlo? Yo estoy usando:

```
$(".adjust-height").closest(.col).css("background-color","red");
```

Pero lo que me esta seleccionando es el primer hijo de cada col-md-5, no el primer col-md-5
Y me gustaría seleccionarlo como padre de .wrapper-img

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, y si quisiera coger dicho col-md-5 como padre de .wrapper-img?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que entiendo lo que tú quieres hacer es seleccionar el primer `.col-md-5` hijo de `.adjust-height`:

```
$(".adjust-height>.col-md-5:first-child").css("background-color","red");
```

Esto lo que hace es seleccionar solo el primer hijo; para más info puedes leer la documentación [aquí](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/#first-child1)

ADICIONAL: si quieres elegir al `.col-md-5` que sea padre de `.wrapper-img` debes usar [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/):

```
$(".adjust-height>.col-md-5").has("wrapper-img").css("background-color","red");
```

> NOTA: Puedes combinar ambos si tienes varios elementos que cumplan una u otra condición y necesites que cumplan ambas, de la siguiente manera:

```
$(".adjust-height>.col-md-5:first-child").has("wrapper-img").css("background-color","red");
```

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, y si quisiera coger dicho col-md-5 como padre de .wrapper-img?

Comment: Agrégalo en la pregunta, que ahora con gusto te lo explico aquí

Comment: Ya lo he hecho, muchas gracias, soy novato en esta plataforma

Comment: Si te ha servido la respuesta, márcala como correcta y bienvenido a StackOverflow en español ;)

Answer (score 0):

El atributo **eq** en jquery te permite indicar el elemento de un listado de items.

```
$(".adjust-height").closest(.col).eq(0).has("wrapper-img").css("background-color","red");
```

Podés leer mas información en la página https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, y si quisiera coger dicho col-md-5 como padre de .wrapper-img?

Comment: Podes usar el condicional has https://api.jquery.com/has/ . Saludos!